# Failed review audit with closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I failed another review audit by voting "leave closed" on this one:

[When do you use std::unordered_map::emplace_hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800405/when-do-you-use-stdunordered-mapemplace-hint)

My vote: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4623624

I usually vote to close if question does not contain failing code or at least specific problem to be solved and this question in my opinion falls into category of "nothing found on Google, help me". I understand that such questions should not be flagged because there are no "technical errors" with it, but close vote seems like a proper way to handle such situation.

Can you enlighten me why I did wrong (or maybe in the rare case why "the system" was wrong)?

Comment: You voted "Leave Closed" but the question is currently open. That is why it is always best to check the question to make sure that it is what review queue says it is.

Comment: You mean that I cannot rely on what review panel shows me and always need to check every question / answer / comment on the "real" link?

Comment: If you think the question should be closed, vote to close and it will never show up as an audit again. The system that picks questions for audits is automatic, and since this question has no downvotes or close votes, the system considers it to be a good question. (Someone's already downvoted it since you posted, so it already won't be an audit question again.)

Comment: The review panel bastardizes the question; it probably showed you zero votes, for example.  That said, the number of votes on the question was not necessary to evaluate it.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I don't say to check the "real" every time but it never hurts to do when in doubt. I'm not sure what your review queue like but because I only stick to tags I know it becomes very clear to me when questions are audits because it feels "robotic".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Showing some code was never a requirement for asking a question on Stack Overflow, although it is strongly encouraged in the Help Center.

As to the "Nothing found on Google" aspect, the proper response for a question that you feel is under-researched is to downvote it.  "Insufficient research" is not a valid close reason, and never was.

Comment: Wat? You mean that my post (deleted: How to get file contents from input type=file) was closed for no reason? I always thot the "rule" of having to provide code that didn't work was stupid.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `icanhazcodez`.  Those kinds of questions are frequently Too Broad or Unclear.

Comment: Well, mine wasn't. It was "how can I use the FileReader API", a pretty simple problem that can be solved with 10 lines of code, so not too broad. And I made sure I was clear.

Comment: I always assumed that question that can be solved just by author actually reading a documentation is subject to closure. Seems like after several years on SO I still need to learn things.

Comment: @Tomasz I never saw any "possibly duplicate of the manual" buttons… Or is that the downvote button?

Comment: @bjb568 That question almost certainly sounds too broad.  It sounds like you have a more specific problem to solve, but you asked a really broad question to try to solve a really specific problem.

Comment: @bjb568: I looked at the post you cited; it's quite the mess.  All I can say is that it would probably never show up in a review audit as a "this post should stay open" example.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Many are, some are not.  Read the actual close reasons and see if they apply or not.  As Robert said, most of those kinds of questions also happen to be close worthy because the people who ask them tend to not be good at asking questions, but those traits are not, in and of themselves, grounds for closure, just an indication that something else *might* be wrong.

Comment: @Servy I want to read a file. It's pretty simple, so answering is possible. It's simple what I want: I want to read a file. It's not a duplicate: I already theroly searched the internet. I checked the manual and MDN, but those were confusing. Future Googlers can benefit of my question. It's so possible to answer that I did, by editing the question since it was already closed.

Comment: @Robert Well, yeah… It had a comment storm, a meta post, a bunch of downvotes, closed, reopen votes, a bad answer, a self-answer-in-question… But shouldn't the question itself be ok?

Comment: @bjb568 This conversation clearly can't go anywhere without me seeing the question, but what you are describing is a question that is *very* broad, and very well documented on the internet, and *not* very useful to other users.

Comment: @Servy I did do an hour of searching and fiddling with the console before I posted it, it wasn't that I didn't attempt a solution. The internet didn't seem to have the answer, so I asked. I assumed that other people could do the same as me, except in the initial googling find my question already posted on SO.

Comment: @bjb568 then why you didn't post the code that failed? You assumed that everyone has your mind context which isn't true. Maybe anyone can do that but I doubt anyone actually did just for the research for you.

Comment: @Tomasz I really had no idea what I was doing. Giving out crap code didn't sound like a way to "improve" the question. I **really** don't want every question on SO to be a debugging question. Can't we have some how-tos too?

Comment: @bjb568 SO is not a place for introductory tutorials to entire topics, a place to just replicate documentation, or a place to write out your entire programming related books.  Questions are designed to be specific and focused.  There is absolutely a place for all of those others things, it's just not on SO.

Comment: @bjb568: That would be a good subject for a new meta post.

Comment: @Servy You're not advising me to go to a *forum*, are you?

Comment: @bjb568 There is a place for them, sure, however tutorials, explanations of entire high level concepts, documentation, books on a subject, etc. don't really fit any better their either.  Tutorials are best posted as stand alone tutorials, as are books, as is documentation.  None of those things fits particularly well in a q/a model.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251574/can-we-expand-which-questions-are-on-topic

Answer (score 10):

I don't know anything about the context of the question in question so this is specifically related to yours:

> I understand that such questions should not be flagged because there are no "technical errors" with it, but close vote seems like a proper way to handle such situation.

This sentence *scares* me. A lot. This implies that Stack Overflow is solely there to debug others code for them. I really, really, hope this isn't the case and that there's a place here for interesting questions to exist.

To answer your question, this question is an audit because it's got no downvotes, has 5 votes and no one has ever voted to close. If you think that this question should not be an audit vote to close or downvote - just have a reason for doing so...

Comment: I usually follow a simple what-to-do algorithm on SO: if it's seriously malformed, "do it for me", rude or sth -> flag, if it's just "I'm kinda lazy, help me" or "I dunno what is going on, here's 2MiB of my code" -> close, if it's a good question but fails at spelling or grammar -> edit, otherwise downvote. Do you see any holes in this?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Several.  First, just because a question is very poorly formatted and very demanding doesn't mean you should flag it as rude; you should downvote/vote to close, probably as unclear.  If you're going to vote to close a question, you should in most cases also be downvoting it, or at least seriously considering doing so.  If a question has a ton of code shown without a good explanation of the problem, it's *probably* too broad or unclear.  A "lazy" question may or may not be too broad, and may or may not be unclear.  It is almost certainly downvote worthy though.

Comment: Not particularly @Tomasz; you might want to consider upvoting occasionally though :-), or voting to close if appropriate rather than flagging. The problem might be that you're looking for _something_ to do. If you don't have domain knowledge and you're at all unsure you might want to consider skipping the review rather than thinking that you must perform an action.

Comment: @Servy: It is a hierarchy, flagged question receives also closure and downvote. I mostly flag only one-sentence-read-crystal-ball and really offensive questions.

Comment: @Ben: This is what I do if question is bad, if I see a good one upvote and comment / answer is what I do (if I can). I'm reviewing questions filtered by my professional work tags (PHP, MySQL, Linux and so on) and if there's any outside of my domain knowledge I flag / close / downvote only if I'm sure that it's poor based on my overall IT experience.

Comment: As I say I don't think you're doing anything _massively_ wrong @Tomasz. However, in this case you've attempted to stop the reopening of a C++ question. This was a test, and it was a test you failed. If it's the first time really don't worry about it. It happens to everyone. If it's the 5th time you need to start taking a serious look at what you're doing.